# I want to rename folder in my android storage automatically using code

Tags: android, file-rename, auto

I once know how to do it but i totally forget
The only thing i remember is i use one of this app to run the code that i write inside of a file
I dont remember which one
~Zarchiver
~Es file explorer
~Mt manager
Im really sure its one of that app and i dont remember the file extension either

Can someone please help me
Maybe anyone here ever do same thing that i do
I need the file extension name, the app and the code
Please and thankyou
*i try to ask chatgpt but curently the server full apparently